# PopModalAsync in OnAppearing Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an xamarin.forms app.

On a page before starting a video I have to **check that the internet connection is turned** on otherwise I show an error message and then **I have to close the page**.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work, the popup is shown, but after i press "ok" **the application freezes and it doesn't work anymore**.

```
    private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            DisplayAlert("WARNING!", "Error message!", "OK");
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
        else
        {

            //...

        }
    }
```

The control is done in the content page's `OnAppearing` event, is that why `Navigation.PopModalAsync()` doesn't work? How can I fix it?

Comment: Use Await and Async

Comment: @ChetanRawat I put async to the method and await to the DisplayAlert but when I press ok the situation does not change, the page is not closed and the app freezes

Comment: Visual Studio gives me notice that it is not possible to wait for the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use asynchronous operations since both `DisplayAlert` and `PopModalAsync` return a task. Also you should override page's OnAppearing method and remove the Appearing event handler.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("WARNING!", "Error message!", "OK");
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
    else
    {

        //...

    }
}
```

Again using `async void` is not recommended and I would suggest using MVVM and not write your code directly on the page's codebehind but this should work for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried, but I get the exception `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: thanks for the advice, being a small project I have not implemented MVVM for the moment

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your modal navigation stack. Is your page wrapped inside a NavigationPage?

Comment: Connectivity and navigation seems okay. i open this content page by doing this `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PlayerPage(param));` from main page

Comment: It's not wrapped inside a NavigationPage

Comment: You should have a proper navigation stack. MainPage should be a NavigationPage containing your first page which in turn pushes your PlayerPage. ```MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageA());```

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll try it now.

Comment: I tried, I did: mainpage (navigation) and as first page homepage. from homepage I push playerpage, the alert goes out but once pressed ok the application crash.

Comment: Strange. You will need to share more of your code because the signature of your ContentPage_Appearing method looks like it serves as an event handler. Are you overriding the OnAppearing method of the Page? How is the ContentPage_Appearing method being called?

Comment: it wasn't override, I tried that but the result doesn't change. I think I have to find another solution for this thing. before contentpage_appearing was called by xaml like `Appearing = ContentPage_Appearing`

Comment: done but nothing. System.NullReferenceException.I don't know really, if I can't find a solution I'll find another way to show the error message.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your project's structure. I don't know if finding a different way might help because you might get a crash further down the line. You should share more of code here.

Comment: Also check if you have an OnAppearing handler in your first page which might be called after the modal page is popped and might contain any null object references.

Comment: Okay, I solved it! Like you said, it was right. I checked the code over and over again and found an error that caused me the exception. Now everything works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and patience :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Microsoft has a quite rich documentation regarding Xamarin. Here is a page regarding navigation that might be useful for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical